# How to access TLS certificates in Jetty Websocket

Tags: java, ssl, jetty

I have a TLS secured connection, on top of which a communication over web sockets is performed. What I want to do is check the attributes contained in the certificate that is used for the TLS connection.

Jetty is used for HTTP communication, and the protocol is going to run as a karaf component.

I tried to dig into layers as deep as possible. I hoped to find something in the  WebsocketComponentServlet. There is the ServletUpgradeRequest at least:

```
public class WebsocketComponentServlet extends WebSocketServlet {
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSocketServletFactory factory) {
        factory.setCreator(new WebSocketCreator() {
        @Override
        public Object createWebSocket(ServletUpgradeRequest req,    ServletUpgradeResponse resp)             
            ...
```

I tried to dig into the HTTPSession or the ServletUpgradeRequest, but I am not able to find the certificate information there. If I go down further, I get to the WebsocketComponent, which contains at least the SSLContextParameters. But besides the key store password, which is correctly set, most fields are empty. 
Am I heading in the right direction or am I entirely missing the point here?

Edit: I guess i need to be more specific. The answer below (thank you for that) points to the usual way of deploying and configuring jetty. I try to access the certicate data from inside of my tests. I included the source code:

```
public class WssProducerConsumerTest extends CamelTestSupport {
    protected static final String TEST_MESSAGE = "Hello World!";
    protected static final int PORT = AvailablePortFinder.getNextAvailable();
    protected Server server;
    private Process tpm2dclient = null;
    private Process tpm2dserver = null;
    private Process ttp = null;
    private File socketServer;
    private File socketClient;
    protected List<Object> messages;
    private static String PWD = "password";

    public void startTestServer() throws Exception {
        // start a simple websocket echo service
        server = new Server(PORT);
        Connector connector = new ServerConnector(server);
        server.addConnector(connector);

        ServletContextHandler ctx = new ServletContextHandler();
        ctx.setContextPath("/");
        ctx.addServlet(TestServletFactory.class.getName(), "/*");

        server.setHandler(ctx);

        server.start();
        assertTrue(server.isStarted());      
    }

    public void stopTestServer() throws Exception {
        server.stop();
        server.destroy();
    }

    @Override
    public void setUp() throws Exception {

        ClassLoader classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
        URL trustStoreURL = classLoader.getResource("jsse/client-truststore.jks");
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", trustStoreURL.getFile());
        System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
        startTestServer();
        super.setUp();
    }

    @Override
    public void tearDown() throws Exception {
        super.tearDown();
        stopTestServer();
    }

    @Test
    public void testTwoRoutes() throws Exception {
        MockEndpoint mock = getMockEndpoint("mock:result");
        mock.expectedBodiesReceived(TEST_MESSAGE);

        template.sendBody("direct:input", TEST_MESSAGE);

        mock.assertIsSatisfied();
    }


    private static SSLContextParameters defineClientSSLContextClientParameters() {

        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/client-keystore.jks").toString());
        ksp.setPassword(PWD);

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyPassword(PWD);
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

        KeyStoreParameters tsp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        tsp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/client-truststore.jks").toString());

        tsp.setPassword(PWD);

        TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
        tmp.setKeyStore(tsp);

        SSLContextServerParameters scsp = new SSLContextServerParameters();
        //scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.REQUIRE.name());
        scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.NONE.name());

        SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
        sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(kmp);
        sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(tmp);
        sslContextParameters.setServerParameters(scsp);


        return sslContextParameters;
    }

    private static SSLContextParameters defineServerSSLContextParameters() {
        KeyStoreParameters ksp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        ksp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/server-keystore.jks").toString());
        ksp.setPassword(PWD);

        KeyManagersParameters kmp = new KeyManagersParameters();
        kmp.setKeyPassword(PWD);
        kmp.setKeyStore(ksp);

        KeyStoreParameters tsp = new KeyStoreParameters();
        tsp.setResource(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("jsse/server-truststore.jks").toString());
        tsp.setPassword(PWD);

        TrustManagersParameters tmp = new TrustManagersParameters();
        tmp.setKeyStore(tsp);

        SSLContextServerParameters scsp = new SSLContextServerParameters();
        //scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.REQUIRE.name());
        scsp.setClientAuthentication(ClientAuthentication.NONE.name());

        SSLContextParameters sslContextParameters = new SSLContextParameters();
        sslContextParameters.setKeyManagers(kmp);
        sslContextParameters.setTrustManagers(tmp);
        sslContextParameters.setServerParameters(scsp);


       return sslContextParameters;
    }

    @Override
    protected RouteBuilder[] createRouteBuilders() throws Exception {
        RouteBuilder[] rbs = new RouteBuilder[2];

        // An ips consumer
        rbs[0] = new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {

                // Needed to configure TLS on the client side
                WsComponent wsComponent = (WsComponent) context.getComponent("ipsclient");
                wsComponent.setSslContextParameters(defineClientSSLContextClientParameters());

                from("direct:input").routeId("foo")
                    .log(">>> Message from direct to WebSocket Client : ${body}")
                    .to("ipsclient://localhost:9292/echo")
                    .log(">>> Message from WebSocket Client to server: ${body}");
                }
        };

        // An ips provider
        rbs[1] = new RouteBuilder() {
            public void configure() {

                    // Needed to configure TLS on the server side
                    WebsocketComponent websocketComponent = (WebsocketComponent) context.getComponent("ipsserver");
                    websocketComponent.setSslContextParameters(defineServerSSLContextParameters());

                    // This route is set to use TLS, referring to the parameters set above
                    from("ipsserver:localhost:9292/echo")
                    .log(">>> Message from WebSocket Server to mock: ${body}")
                    .to("mock:result");
            }
        };
        return rbs;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note: the following answer will only work under the following conditions
>
> 1. The `ServerConnector` has HTTPS/SSL/TLS support.
> 2. The `ServerConnector` has an appropriate `HttpConfiguration` that specifies that its traffic is secure
> 3. The `ServerConnector` has the `SecureRequestCustomizer` added to its `HttpConfiguration` (this does things such as populating the `HttpServletRequest` attributes with the various servlet spec details about the secure connection)
> 4. The Request was received on this `ServerConnector`
> 5. You terminate SSL/TLS at Jetty (if you terminate SSL/TLS before Jetty, then Jetty does not have access to this certificate information)

You have a few options in `org.eclipse.jetty.websocket.servlet.ServletUpgradeRequest`

- [`getCertificates()`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.13.v20161014/jetty-websocket/websocket-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.java#L104-L107) returns the `X509Certificate[]` chain
- [`getServletAttribute("javax.servlet.request.ssl_session_id")`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.13.v20161014/jetty-websocket/websocket-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.java#L271-L273) returns a String representing the SSLSession ID
- [`getServletAttribute("javax.servlet.request.cipher_suite")`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.13.v20161014/jetty-websocket/websocket-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.java#L271-L273) returns a String representing the SSLSession Cipher Suite
- [`getServletAttribute("javax.servlet.request.key_size")`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.13.v20161014/jetty-websocket/websocket-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.java#L271-L273) returns an Integer representing the Cipher Suite Key Length
- [`getServletAttribute("javax.servlet.request.X509Certificate")`](https://github.com/eclipse/jetty.project/blob/jetty-9.3.13.v20161014/jetty-websocket/websocket-servlet/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/websocket/servlet/ServletUpgradeRequest.java#L271-L273) returns Certificates Chain in use

Comment: Thank you. I already tried that and the cert chain is always null :\ This is why i thought i might be on the wrong track all together...

Comment: added some requirements to the answer for ya

Comment: Hi, sorry for the delay in responding. We are talking about the package org.eclipse.jetty.server.ServerConnector, right? How could i make sure the first three properties are met? If i look at the source code, i can not even see a HttpConfiguration class.

Comment: See [ServerConnectorHttps.java at github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook](https://github.com/jetty-project/embedded-jetty-cookbook/blob/master/src/main/java/org/eclipse/jetty/cookbook/ServerConnectorHttps.java)

Comment: Thank you! I start to understand the problem now. If i configure jetty in the configuration files, i can specify the required components. I try to access the TLS specifics out of my test code. Is there any way i can do that? I added the source code to my question. The general way i asked the question was maybe a bit misleading.